# Are there any preliminary results from Mars lander InSight's RISE antennas?

Tags: mars, nasa, planetary-science, insight

@karthikeyan's excellent [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/32238/12102) links to [The Rotation and Interior Structure Experiment on the InSight Mission to Mars](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s11214-018-0530-5) (Folkner, W.M., Dehant, V., Le Maistre, S. et al. Space Sci Rev (2018) 214: 100. https://doi.org/10.1007/s11214-018-0530-5), and includes this image from there.

**Question:** Are there any preliminary results from Mars lander InSight's RISE antennas? Have they been at least tested yet? If so, what did they transmit and/or receive?

[image: Mars InSight lander's RISE antennas]

Related: [3D celestial puzzler; why InSight's two RISE horns point slightly south of east, and north of west?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32241/12102)

Answer (score 2):

The paper "[Initial results from the InSight mission on Mars](https://eorder.sheridan.com/3_0/app/orders/9194/article.php)" published on 24 February 2020 in the journal *Nature Geoscience* states

> HP$^3$ and RISE have not yet collected sufficient data for meaningful analysis; thus their results will not be discussed here.

The webpage for [RISE](https://mars.nasa.gov/insight/spacecraft/instruments/rise/) does not report any problems with that instrument.  In contrast, NASA has been very open about the problems with [HP$^3$](https://mars.nasa.gov/insight/spacecraft/instruments/hp3).

It therefore seems that RISE is functional, but there simply isn't enough data to draw any meaningful conclusions.

Comment: okay thanks! Here's another copy: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/339463051_Initial_results_from_the_InSight_mission_on_Mars