# What are the largest distances between two spacecraft that have been determined to a meter or so accuracy? How were these done?

Tags: record, delay-doppler, doppler-ranging, ranging, grail

[This answer to *Radio Telescope / DSN Node in L4 and/or L5*](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/58246/12102) presents the challenge of implementing "very long" VLBI using the ~1 AU distance between Earth and a Sun-Earth triangular libration point orbit as a baseline.

For radio astronomy interferometry there are ways in post-processing to reconstruct the baseline to millimeter accuracy, but since these involve search and optimization, you need a good starting point that's close to correct. For the Event Horizon Telescope that was done with GPS plus atomic clocks at each dish plus "fringe maximization" from a calibration/reference target.

- [Precise Event Horizon Telescope locations?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/473320/83380)

But for space-based VLBI with a circa 1 AU baseline there's no GPS to get a starting point for a fringe maximization search. Therefore I'd like to ask the following to get an idea of the state of the art inter-spacecraft ranging:

**Question:** What are the largest distances between two spacecraft that have been determined to a meter or so accuracy? How were these done?

#### Example:

The Gravity Recovery and Interior Laboratory or [GRAIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRAIL) spacecraft pair were used to map the Moon's gravity field to very high spatial resolution and precision using precise radiometric range and range-rate links in a triangle between the two spacecraft and between each spacecraft and Earth.

[image: GRAIL lunar probes, NASA Press release, 12 December 2007]

GRAIL lunar probes, NASA Press release, 12 December 2007 [source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:GRAIL.jpg)

Comment: Wow, cool followup-question! Absolutely true. If we go L4 AND L5 we'd even have $\sqrt{3}AU$ (around 1.7AU) baseline (L4/5 each form a same sided triangle with sun and earth as the base, so the distance between earth and L4/5 is 1AU each and the distance between L4 and L5 is twice the "height" of the triangle).